How to test Django models against a DB without manage.py in a standalone package using pytest and GitHub Actions?
Context:

I am developing a standalone Django package that is intended to be added to existing Django projects.
This package includes Django models with methods that interact directly with a database.
I want to write tests for these methods using pytest and pytest-django.
I need to run these tests in a CI/CD environment, specifically using GitHub Actions.

Problems Encountered:

Database Setup:

Since this is a standalone package, it does not include a manage.py file.
This makes it challenging to run typical Django management commands like migrate to set up the database schema for testing.


Table Creation:

I encounter errors indicating that the table for my model does not exist because the necessary migrations are not applied.
This is problematic because my tests need to interact with the database tables directly.


Fixtures and Setup:

I need to ensure the database tables are created and populated with initial data before the tests run.
My attempts to use pytest fixtures and manually create database tables within the tests have not been successful.



What I've Tried:

Using pytest fixtures to set up the initial database state.
Manually creating database tables within the test setup using direct SQL execution.
Using the mixer library to populate the database with test data.

Desired Outcome:

A reliable method to ensure the necessary database tables for my models are created before running the tests.
Proper setup and teardown of test data within the standalone package.
Integration with CI/CD pipelines like GitHub Actions without relying on manage.py commands.

Additional Information:

I am using an in-memory SQLite database for faster test execution.
The test environment should be isolated and not rely on external databases or services.

I am looking for guidance on how to approach this problem or best practices for testing Django models in a standalone package using pytest and pytest-django. Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

You don't need manage.py to run migrate. The same commands are available via the django-admin command that Django installs, but you'll need to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable that manage.py would ordinarily set.
IOW, if you'd generally run python manage.py and your project settings are myproject.settings, you can just as well run env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings django-admin migrate.
That said, that's not your issue here – pytest-django will deal with setting up and tearing down a testing database for you. Generally, when developing a Django package, you'd have a testing project and app next to it to host the package for development use.
An example (of a standalone package, tested with GitHub Actions) is here (repository maintained by yours truly); lippukala is the reusable package, and lippukala_test_app is the package that hosts the settings for pytest-django to use; there's a stanza
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = "lippukala_test_app.settings"

in the pyproject.toml file that makes that work.

Thanks for the response! The lippukala example was helpful. Do you know if it's possible to explicitly interact with the database and query it using pytest? I'm struggling to see how to save and read instances in the test database, as that's part of what I'm testing.

Yes – just do it as you'd do in any code (make sure your test is marked with @pytest.mark.django_db; in the linked example, it's marked via a module-wide pytestmark).
